# How to do geometric correction of remote sensing data in R?

Tags: r

My challenge is to replace most of the remote sensing commercial tools with R code (I'm teaching assistant at the University and I would like to move to open source R code to show the added values to the students). I'm currently stuck as I cannot find a way to perform **geometric correction** of remote sensing data.
The exercise should be:

1. Select **Ground Control Points** on both the georeferenced image and the image to correct
2. Use **polynomial mapping** for image correction (students should try to test different ** polynomial order** and calculate the **RMSE** for each step)
3. Warp the image in a defined projection using the interpolation method (either nearest neighbour, bi-linear interpolation, cubic convolution)

The 2 last steps could be processed using rgdal but it is not interactive with R.
More precisely, is there a R tool able to interactively select points on two figure and retrieve their location ?

Comment: this is a good question in general (although I would consider using a more specialized open-source tool such as QGIS), but not a very good fit for StackOverflow, which looks for programming questions.  Maybe consider asking on http://gis.stackexchange.com/ ???

Comment: Hm?  You don't like using  `Rgdal` ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft -- Unless I'm missing something, **rgdal** doesn't seem to include an interface to [**`gdalwarp`**](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html).

Comment: @BenBolker: Thx. I'll ask it also on gis.stackexchange. According to me, the fact to have an interface in R to be able to select points on 2 figures and to retrieve their location information interactively is an exciting programming challenge. That's the reason why I'm still looking for answers/ideas on stackoverflow.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the just-published **gdalUtils** package. It includes a function `gdalwarp()` that's an R wrapper for the **gdal** function of the same name. (Use the function's `r=` argument to set the resampling method to one of `"near"|"bilinear"|"cubic"|"cubicspline"|"lanczos"|"average"|"mode"`.) I just tried out the example in `?gdalwarp` on my Windows machine, and it worked without a hitch.